# plot clusters of kmeans of sparse matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have a python script which do clustering over a data file which is in svmlight format.
I use the function `sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file` to load the data from the data file.
I know that this function returns a sparse matrix.
I need to scatter plot the clusters, can any body help me please.
This what I have done:

```
import sklearn.datasets
import sys
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
dataFilename = sys.argv[1]
X, y = sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file(dataFilename)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
kmeans.fit(X)
labels = kmeans.labels_
print(labels)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Comment: I have edited my post which shows what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the dataset, I would suggest the following:

- Since `load_svmlight_file()` returns a sparse matrix, **turn `X` into a NumPy array using `samples = X.toarray()`** prior to fitting the model.
- **Plot two features** (for example) of the dataset using:
  `plt.scatter(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], c=labels)`. This colours the clusters by their predicted labels.
- Follow this with `plt.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], marker='D')` to see the location of the centroids with diamonds.

**Note** that `samples[:,n]` represents an array containing the sample values for the `n`th feature of the dataset.

I hope this helps. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I convert the matrix to numpy array I got a numpy array which contains a lot of zeros like follows:[0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.16 0.   0.   0.  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.41 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.   0.   0.43 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.1  0. 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]

Comment: Data set looks like the follows:  0 11:0.38 21:0.89 
1 11:0.3 21:0.92 
2 11:0.36 21:0.78 
3 11:0.3 21:0.8 
4 11:0.32 21:0.82 
5 11:0.2 21:0.64 31:0.25 41:0.03 
6 31:0.81 41:0.32 
7 31:0.79 41:0.33 
8 31:0.81 41:0.3 
9 31:0.88 41:0.25